# Analyzing Apparent .NET 1.1 Windows Service Hang

Tags: .net, windbg, .net-1.1

This dump file is .NET 1.1 so cannot use sosex or DebugDiag, and the SOS available cmds are more limited than normal. I do not have the source for the application. The application is running as Windows service has a timer object that does data processing every 5 seconds. After about 1 day of running it stops processing data with no exceptions raised in application's log. Some WinDbg cmds are failing because it says ntdll.dll symbols are not available, despite the fact they seem to be loading find. One of the threads is waiting on object \KernelObjects\LowMemoryCondition, I wonder if this is potentially related to the problem. Also in !threadpool timers is set to 0, but there is supposed to be a timer that fires the event. Here is current analysis, any recommended next steps to determine why app appears to be in hung state?

```
    ************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Version 14393 MP (2 procs) Free x86 compatible
Product: Server, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
10.0.14393.2430 (rs1_release_inmarket_aim.180806-1810)
Machine Name:
Debug session time: Fri Mar 20 13:15:42.000 2020 (UTC + 11:00)
System Uptime: 20 days 9:56:32.552
Process Uptime: 1 days 3:33:38.000
...............................................
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
eax=00000000 ebx=0000030c ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=0000030c
eip=77e8ed8c esp=0019f368 ebp=0019f3d8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc:
77e8ed8c c20c00          ret     0Ch
||2:2:010> |
.  2    id: 2138    examine name: c:\service\AppName_n2.exe
||2:2:010> !peb
PEB at 00360000
error 3 InitTypeRead( nt!_PEB at 00360000)...
||2:2:010> !cs
Bad symbols for NTDLL (error 3). Aborting.
||2:2:010> !sym noisy
noisy mode - symbol prompts on
||2:2:010> .symfix C:\symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: SRV*C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xE
         C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         wntdll.pdb
         D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb - file not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pd_ - file not found
SYMSRV:  UNC: C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\file.ptr - file not found
SYMSRV:  HTTPGET: /download/symbols/wntdll.pdb/D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31/wntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  HttpQueryInfo: 801900c8 - HTTP_STATUS_OK
SYMSRV:  wntdll.pdb from https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols: 1765376 bytescopied      
SYMSRV:  PATH: C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: SRV*C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0xF
         C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         wntdll.pdb
         D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31
SYMSRV:  PATH: C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: SRV*C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
SYMSRV:  BYINDEX: 0x10
         C:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
         wntdll.pdb
         D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31
SYMSRV:  PATH: C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb
SYMSRV:  RESULT: 0x00000000
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  
        C:\symbols\wntdll.pdb\D870D66A94EA44EF8A4124640E0245F31\wntdll.pdb
0:000> ~*k

.  0  Id: 2138.fc Suspend: 0 Teb: 00363000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0019f364 77cd5e89 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
01 0019f3d8 77cd5de2 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99
02 0019f3ec 7727b322 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12
03 0019f4ac 7728cb71 sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+0xe5
04 0019f55c 7727a0ac sechost!ScDispatcherLoop+0xd1
05 0019f598 030bb29a sechost!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW+0x5c
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
06 00000000 00000000 0x30bb29a

   1  Id: 2138.2390 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00366000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0728fd50 77ce3560 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
01 0728fee4 77ce3458 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
02 0728ff00 791d25d5 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03 0728ff68 791d254c mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0x3d35
04 0728ff80 76ee62c4 mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0x3cac
05 0728ff94 77e81e39 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
06 0728ffdc 77e81e04 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
07 0728ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   2  Id: 2138.2334 Suspend: 0 Teb: 00369000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0946fd6c 77ce3560 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
01 0946ff00 77ce3458 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
02 0946ff1c 79262a5f KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03 0946ff3c 791bbea4 mscorwks!DllGetClassObjectInternal+0x2bd0c
04 0946ff80 76ee62c4 mscorwks!Ordinal77+0xbea4
05 0946ff94 77e81e39 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
06 0946ffdc 77e81e04 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
07 0946ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   3  Id: 2138.2380 Suspend: 0 Teb: 0037b000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0a47f9b8 77ce3560 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc
01 0a47fb4c 792976dc KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
02 0a47fb7c 79297c3d mscorwks!CorMarkThreadInThreadPool+0x2a50
03 0a47fbd0 793389ff mscorwks!CorMarkThreadInThreadPool+0x2fb1
04 0a47fc18 09b10740 mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces+0x9333f
05 0a47fc88 09cee68e 0x9b10740
06 0a47fca8 791da434 0x9cee68e
07 0a47fdb8 791da58a mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0xbb94
08 0a47fe68 791da5f6 mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0xbcea
09 0a47fe90 792e518c mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0xbd56
0a 0a47fedc 792e525b mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces+0x3facc
0b 0a47ff80 76ee62c4 mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces+0x3fb9b
0c 0a47ff94 77e81e39 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
0d 0a47ffdc 77e81e04 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
0e 0a47ffec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

   4  Id: 2138.21c8 Suspend: 0 Teb: 0037e000 Unfrozen
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0a1efe7c 77ce462a ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc
01 0a1efee4 77ce458f KERNELBASE!SleepEx+0x8a
02 0a1efef4 792e9ebe KERNELBASE!Sleep+0xf
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03 0a1eff80 76ee62c4 mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces+0x447fe
04 0a1eff94 77e81e39 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
05 0a1effdc 77e81e04 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f
06 0a1effec 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000> !runaway
 User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
    0:fc       0 days 0:00:00.406
    4:21c8     0 days 0:00:00.093
    3:2380     0 days 0:00:00.015
    2:2334     0 days 0:00:00.000
    1:2390     0 days 0:00:00.000
0:000> !locks
NTSDEXTS: invalid _LIST_ENTRY size 0
0:000> kv
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0019f364 77cd5e89 0000030c 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc (FPO: [3,0,0])
01 0019f3d8 77cd5de2 0000030c ffffffff 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x99 (FPO: [SEH])
02 0019f3ec 7727b322 0000030c ffffffff 40694160 KERNELBASE!WaitForSingleObject+0x12 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
03 0019f4ac 7728cb71 00000000 000004d3 0000f7a0 sechost!ScSendResponseReceiveControls+0xe5 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
04 0019f55c 7727a0ac 40694054 0019f90c 0019f5bc sechost!ScDispatcherLoop+0xd1 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
05 0019f598 030bb29a 0300d688 00000000 0300d688 sechost!StartServiceCtrlDispatcherW+0x5c (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
WARNING: Frame IP not in any known module. Following frames may be wrong.
06 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0x30bb29a
0:000> !handle 30c f
Handle 0000030c
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  65534
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting

0:000> ~1s
eax=791d4d45 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000003 edi=00000003
eip=77e8f31c esp=0728fd54 ebp=0728fee4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc:
77e8f31c c21400          ret     14h
0:001> kv
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0728fd50 77ce3560 00000003 0728ff24 00000001 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
01 0728fee4 77ce3458 00000003 0728ff24 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0 (FPO: [SEH])
02 0728ff00 791d25d5 00000003 0728ff24 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03 0728ff68 791d254c 00000000 791d4d45 791d4d45 mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0x3d35
etc
0:001> dd 0728ff24
0728ff24  000001cc 000001d4 000001c4 00000000
etc
0:001> !handle 000001cc f
Handle 000001cc
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  65538
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting
0:001> !handle 1d4 f
Handle 000001d4
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  65538
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting
0:001> !handle 1c4 f
Handle 000001c4
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  65538
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting
0:001> ~2s
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000002 edi=00000002
eip=77e8f31c esp=0946fd70 ebp=0946ff00 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000212
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc:
77e8f31c c21400          ret     14h
0:002> kv
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0946fd6c 77ce3560 00000002 793dcc58 00000001 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
01 0946ff00 77ce3458 00000002 793dcc58 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0 (FPO: [SEH])
02 0946ff1c 79262a5f 00000002 793dcc58 00000000 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjects+0x18 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03 0946ff3c 791bbea4 00000224 791d0020 791d0020 mscorwks!DllGetClassObjectInternal+0x2bd0c
etc
0:002> dd 793dcc58
793dcc58  00000218 00000224 0000021c 00000000
etc
0:002> !handle 218 f
Handle 00000218
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0x10
  GrantedAccess 0x100001:
         Synch
         QueryState
  HandleCount   16
  PointerCount  462374
  Name          \KernelObjects\LowMemoryCondition
  Object specific information
    Event Type Manual Reset
    Event is Waiting
0:002> !handle 224 f
Handle 00000224
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  65527
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting
0:002> ~3s
eax=00000000 ebx=00000001 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000001 edi=00000001
eip=77e8f31c esp=0a47f9bc ebp=0a47fb4c iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000202
ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc:
77e8f31c c21400          ret     14h
0:003> kv
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0a47f9b8 77ce3560 00000001 0a47fc2c 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc (FPO: [5,0,0])
01 0a47fb4c 792976dc 00000001 0a47fc2c 00000001 KERNELBASE!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0 (FPO: [SEH])
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
02 0a47fb7c 79297c3d 00000001 0a47fc2c 00000001 mscorwks!CorMarkThreadInThreadPool+0x2a50
03 0a47fbd0 793389ff 00000001 0a47fc2c 00000001 mscorwks!CorMarkThreadInThreadPool+0x2fb1
04 0a47fc18 09b10740 0a47fc24 00000000 ffffffff mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces+0x9333f
05 0a47fc88 09cee68e 0a47fcc0 00000000 791b30f0 0x9b10740
06 0a47fca8 791da434 0a47fcf4 00000000 0a47fccc 0x9cee68e
07 0a47fdb8 791da58a 09b26e03 02fcba50 0047fdd8 mscorwks!CoInitializeCor+0xbb94
etc
0:003> dd a47fc2c
0a47fc2c  0000035c ffffffff 0000035c 0a47fce4
etc
0:003> !handle 35c f
Handle 0000035c
  Type          Event
  Attributes    0
  GrantedAccess 0x1f0003:
         Delete,ReadControl,WriteDac,WriteOwner,Synch
         QueryState,ModifyState
  HandleCount   2
  PointerCount  56602
  Name          <none>
  Object specific information
    Event Type Auto Reset
    Event is Waiting
0:003> ~4s
eax=00000000 ebx=0a1efec0 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=00000000 edi=0a1efec0
eip=77e8f0ac esp=0a1efe80 ebp=0a1efee4 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz ac po nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000212
ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc:
77e8f0ac c20800          ret     8
0:004> kv
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
00 0a1efe7c 77ce462a 00000000 0a1efec0 4a2725fc ntdll!NtDelayExecution+0xc (FPO: [2,0,0])
01 0a1efee4 77ce458f 000001f4 00000000 0a1eff80 KERNELBASE!SleepEx+0x8a (FPO: [SEH])
02 0a1efef4 792e9ebe 000001f4 f56e4f7a 00000e55 KERNELBASE!Sleep+0xf (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
03 0a1eff80 76ee62c4 00000000 76ee62a0 4b5d637e mscorwks!ReleaseFusionInterfaces+0x447fe
04 0a1eff94 77e81e39 00000000 4a49bce4 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24 (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
05 0a1effdc 77e81e04 ffffffff 77ea36b9 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x2f (FPO: [SEH])
06 0a1effec 00000000 792e9e6a 00000000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b (FPO: [Non-Fpo])
||2:2:013> .load C:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\sos.dll
||2:2:013> !EEVersion
1.1.4322.573 retail
Workstation build
||2:2:013> !threadpool
CPU utilization 12%
Worker Thread: Total: 0 Running: 0 Idle: 0 MaxLimit: 50 MinLimit: 2
Work Request in Queue: 0
--------------------------------------
Number of Timers: 0
--------------------------------------
Completion Port Thread: Total: 0 Free: 0 MaxFree: 4 CurrentLimit: 0 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 2
||2:2:013> !threads
ThreadCount: 5
UnstartedThread: 1
BackgroundThread: 3
PendingThread: 0
DeadThread: 0
                             PreEmptive   GC Alloc               Lock     
       ID ThreadOBJ    State     GC       Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
 10    fc 02fbb460      a020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 02fb5838     0 MTA System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException
 12  2334 02fbcc78      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 02fb5838     0 MTA (Finalizer)
XXX  234c 03018a90  81800220 Enabled  072d7d4c:072d7da0 02fb5838     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
XXX     0 03019660      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 02fb5838     0 Ukn
 13  2380 03000a30   2001220 Enabled  072ba3f0:072bbda0 02fb5838     0 Ukn
||2:2:013> !syncblk -all
Index SyncBlock MonitorHeld Recursion   Thread  ThreadID     Object Waiting
    1 00000000                                             07292538
    2 00000000                                             07295b28
    3 02fdce74            0         0        0     none    07291114 System.AppDomain
    4 02fdcdc4            0         0        0     none    0729ba08 Borland.Vcl.TFNWndProc
    5 02fdcdf0            0         0        0     none    072a3220 Borland.Vcl.TFNWndProc
    6 00000000                                             072acd28
    7 02fdce48            0         0        0     none    072a33b0 Borland.Vcl.TFNWndProc
    8 02fdcea0            0         0        0     none    072a6e14 System.__ComObject
    9 02fdcecc            0         0        0     none    072a84d4 System.ServiceProcess.NativeMethods/ServiceMainCallback
   10 02fdcef8            0         0        0     none    072a850c System.ServiceProcess.NativeMethods/ServiceControlCallbackEx
   11 02fdce1c            0         0        0     none    072b034c System.Threading.Thread
   12 02fdcf24            0         0        0     none    072b0250 Microsoft.Win32.SafeNativeMethods/TimerAPCProc
-----------------------------
Total           13
ComCallWrapper  0
ComPlusWrapper  1
ComClassFactory 0
Free            0
||2:2:013> !eestack -EE
---------------------------------------------
Thread  10
Current frame: 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller,Callee
0019f5c4 09ce4805 (MethodDesc 0x30c8a38 +0x1bd System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run)
0019f5f0 09ce3f87 (MethodDesc 0x30c8a48 +0x27 System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run)
0019f5fc 09ce356c (MethodDesc 0x30c52a8 +0x2c AppName_N2.Units.AppName_N2.AppName_N2)
---------------------------------------------
Thread  12
Current frame: 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller,Callee
0946fdf8 09ceb422 (MethodDesc 0x99aca78 +0x1a Borland.Vcl.TResData.Finalize)
---------------------------------------------
Thread  13
Current frame: 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller,Callee
0a47fc50 09ce51be (MethodDesc 0x99797a0 +0x56 System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne)
0a47fc88 09cee68e (MethodDesc 0x9afe588 +0x1e System.Timers.Timer/WaitableTimer.ListenerThread)

||2:2:013> !COMState
     ID     TEB   APT    APTId CallerTID Context
 10   fc 00363000 MTA     55a4         0 02fefe90
 11 2390 00366000 Ukn
 12 2334 00369000 MTA        0         0 02fefe90
 13 2380 0037b000 Ukn        0         0 02fefe90
 14 21c8 0037e000 Ukn

||2:2:013> !dumpheap -type System.Timers.Timer
 Address       MT     Size
072acd28 09afca04       56
total 1 objects
Statistics:
      MT    Count TotalSize Class Name
 9afca04        1        56 System.Timers.Timer
Total 1 objects

||2:2:013> !dumpobj 072acd28
Name: System.Timers.Timer
MethodTable 0x09afca04
EEClass 0x09cd0828
Size 56(0x38) bytes
mdToken: 020002ec  (c:\windows\assembly\gac\system\1.0.5000.0__b77a5c561934e089\system.dll)
FieldDesc*: 09afc7f4
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
0313643c  40000b6        4                CLASS   instance 00000000 __identity
030c878c  4000502        8                CLASS   instance 00000000 site
030c878c  4000503        c                CLASS   instance 00000000 events
030c878c  4000501       50                CLASS     static 072a19e0 EventDisposed
09afca04  4001542       10        System.Double   instance 5000.000000 interval
09afca04  4001543       2c       System.Boolean   instance        1 enabled
09afca04  4001544       2d       System.Boolean   instance        0 initializing
09afca04  4001545       2e       System.Boolean   instance        0 delayedEnable
09afca04  4001546       18                CLASS   instance 072acde0 onIntervalElapsed
09afca04  4001547       28         System.Int32   instance      768 handle
09afca04  4001548       2f       System.Boolean   instance        1 autoReset
09afca04  4001549       1c                CLASS   instance 00000000 synchronizingObject
09afca04  400154a       20                CLASS   instance 072b0250 apcCallback
09afca04  400154b       24                CLASS   instance 072b026c threadPoolCallback
09afca04  400154c       30       System.Boolean   instance        0 disposed
||2:2:013> .foreach /pS 3 /ps 2 (ex {!dumpheap -type Exception }){ !dumpobj ${ex} }
Name: System.OutOfMemoryException
MethodTable 0x0313590c
EEClass 0x097b70f4
Size 64(0x40) bytes
mdToken: 02000017  (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll)
FieldDesc*: 00000000
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
03135734  400001d        4                CLASS   instance 00000000 _className
03135734  400001e        8                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethod
03135734  400001f        c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethodString
03135734  4000020       10                CLASS   instance 00000000 _message
03135734  4000021       14                CLASS   instance 00000000 _innerException
03135734  4000022       18                CLASS   instance 00000000 _helpURL
03135734  4000023       1c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTrace
03135734  4000024       20                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTraceString
03135734  4000025       24                CLASS   instance 00000000 _remoteStackTraceString
03135734  4000026       2c         System.Int32   instance        0 _remoteStackIndex
03135734  4000027       30         System.Int32   instance -2147024882 _HResult
03135734  4000028       28                CLASS   instance 00000000 _source
03135734  4000029       34         System.Int32   instance        0 _xptrs
03135734  400002a       38         System.Int32   instance -532459699 _xcode
Name: System.StackOverflowException
MethodTable 0x031359e4
EEClass 0x097b7158
Size 64(0x40) bytes
mdToken: 02000018  (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll)
FieldDesc*: 00000000
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
03135734  400001d        4                CLASS   instance 00000000 _className
03135734  400001e        8                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethod
03135734  400001f        c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethodString
03135734  4000020       10                CLASS   instance 00000000 _message
03135734  4000021       14                CLASS   instance 00000000 _innerException
03135734  4000022       18                CLASS   instance 00000000 _helpURL
03135734  4000023       1c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTrace
03135734  4000024       20                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTraceString
03135734  4000025       24                CLASS   instance 00000000 _remoteStackTraceString
03135734  4000026       2c         System.Int32   instance        0 _remoteStackIndex
03135734  4000027       30         System.Int32   instance -2147023895 _HResult
03135734  4000028       28                CLASS   instance 00000000 _source
03135734  4000029       34         System.Int32   instance        0 _xptrs
03135734  400002a       38         System.Int32   instance -532459699 _xcode
Name: System.ExecutionEngineException
MethodTable 0x03135abc
EEClass 0x097b71bc
Size 64(0x40) bytes
mdToken: 02000019  (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll)
FieldDesc*: 00000000
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
03135734  400001d        4                CLASS   instance 00000000 _className
03135734  400001e        8                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethod
03135734  400001f        c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethodString
03135734  4000020       10                CLASS   instance 00000000 _message
03135734  4000021       14                CLASS   instance 00000000 _innerException
03135734  4000022       18                CLASS   instance 00000000 _helpURL
03135734  4000023       1c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTrace
03135734  4000024       20                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTraceString
03135734  4000025       24                CLASS   instance 00000000 _remoteStackTraceString
03135734  4000026       2c         System.Int32   instance        0 _remoteStackIndex
03135734  4000027       30         System.Int32   instance -2146233082 _HResult
03135734  4000028       28                CLASS   instance 00000000 _source
03135734  4000029       34         System.Int32   instance        0 _xptrs
03135734  400002a       38         System.Int32   instance -532459699 _xcode
Name: System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException
MethodTable 0x09b225d4
EEClass 0x09967fc8
Size 64(0x40) bytes
mdToken: 020000cc  (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll)
FieldDesc*: 00000000
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
03135734  400001d        4                CLASS   instance 00000000 _className
03135734  400001e        8                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethod
03135734  400001f        c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _exceptionMethodString
03135734  4000020       10                CLASS   instance 072a447c _message
03135734  4000021       14                CLASS   instance 00000000 _innerException
03135734  4000022       18                CLASS   instance 00000000 _helpURL
03135734  4000023       1c                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTrace
03135734  4000024       20                CLASS   instance 00000000 _stackTraceString
03135734  4000025       24                CLASS   instance 00000000 _remoteStackTraceString
03135734  4000026       2c         System.Int32   instance        0 _remoteStackIndex
03135734  4000027       30         System.Int32   instance -2146233064 _HResult
03135734  4000028       28                CLASS   instance 00000000 _source
03135734  4000029       34         System.Int32   instance        0 _xptrs
03135734  400002a       38         System.Int32   instance -532459699 _xcode
Name: Borland.Vcl.EIniFileException/@MetaEIniFileException
MethodTable 0x09afef6c
EEClass 0x09cd158c
Size 20(0x14) bytes
mdToken: 02000546  (c:\service\AppName_n2.exe)
FieldDesc*: 09afeef4
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
099a8ecc  4000001        c            VALUETYPE   instance start at 072afeb8 FInstanceTypeHandle
099a8ecc  4000002        4                CLASS   instance 00000000 FInstanceType
099a8ecc  4000003        8                CLASS   instance 00000000 FClassParent
09afef6c  4000d1b       28                CLASS     static 072afeac @Instance
||2:2:013> !dumpobj 072a447c
Name: System.String
MethodTable 0x031342d8
EEClass 0x097b6d70
Size 176(0xb0) bytes
mdToken: 0200000f  (c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v1.1.4322\mscorlib.dll)
String: Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
FieldDesc*: 03133628
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type       Attr    Value Name
031342d8  4000013        4         System.Int32   instance       79 m_arrayLength
031342d8  4000014        8         System.Int32   instance       78 m_stringLength
031342d8  4000015        c          System.Char   instance       4f m_firstChar
031342d8  4000016        0                CLASS     shared   static Empty
    >> Domain:Value 02fb5838:0729121c <<
031342d8  4000017        4                CLASS     shared   static WhitespaceChars
    >> Domain:Value 02fb5838:07291230 <<
```

Comment: "I do not have the source for the application" is wrong. With the dump you can extract all assemblies out, and then decompile them. It is .NET Framework apps that we are talking about, not C/C++.

Comment: Yes I have done that, but it is not a recompilable/exactly the same as the original source code (although quite close) I am looking through that to find potential bugs but haven't yet noticed anything obvious ....

Comment: Also SOS for .NET 1.1 doesn't have the !savemodule command, however I had been able to get a copy of the original exe.

Comment: Why not start a .NET 1.1 hang analysis the same way as every other hung application? 1. Load the dump in DebugDiag and have it analyzed. 2. run `!analyze -hang`

Comment: Because .NET 1.1 doesn't have MSCORDACWKS.dll (As far as I can tell, there are no DLLs even with same exported functions) which is required for DebugDiag to do an analysis. MSCORDACWKS.dll must match the exact build of .NET your program is running against.

Comment: !analyze -v -hang is no good in this scenario, because I get the same result even if it's not hang, it shows false result i.e. APPLICATION_HANG_BusyHang_cfffffff_sechost.dll!ScSendResponseReceiveControls; which it shows for the .NET 1.1 state whether it's hung or not

Comment: Can you share the dump? I've not done .NET 1.1 analysis for >8 years

Comment: I actually managed to work it out, I will share answer later. Actually it is Timer bug is .NET 1.1 framework as the random generator is not random, it is just result of GetTickCount() and it calls CreateWaitableTimer with name ServerTimer<object hash code><random number> Multiple process on machine if they run at same time they have collision and can't create the timer. (i.e. they try to create waitable timer with same name, and one process will fail